# Not Showing Pull Request in Amplify Web Preview

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

I have just started using Amplify to build my web app, and set Web Preview by connecting with Github (followed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amplify/latest/userguide/pr-previews.html)).
Even though Amplify App is integrated into my Github organization/repository, Web Preview does not get triggered and no pull requests are shown.

Could you tell me what causes this and how to solve the problem?
(e.g., Need to use Github Team/Enterprise plan?)[image]

Comment: Though I have not found an exact answer, organization repository does affect the problem. The above is under my organization repository which does not work (Team Plan does not affect), but my private repository works perfectly with AWS Amplify Console Web Preview.